# ColdFusion: CFID and CFToken change on each page request

Tags: security, session, cookies, coldfusion

I have been asked to use J2EE Variables and not store the `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` in cookies, as the CFID is reported as non-compliant: [Predictable Cookie Session ID's Reported by Compliance Tests](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/predictable-cookie-session-ids-reported.html)

- In my Application.cfm, I have added **setclientcookies="false"**.  This stops the CFID and CFToken being written as cookies.
- In the ColdFusion Admin, I have enabled J2EE Session Variables

So I now have a cookie with `JESSIONID`, and a session variable with `URLToken` containing CFID and CFTOKEN. However, every time I refresh the page, the CFID and CFTOKEN change. They do not persist as they did before. Which mean our admin login system fails.

I have done my own googling, but have found nothing so far. One suggestion I found was to write code to persist the CFID and CFTOKEN. However, this doesn't feel like a good solution.

Any suggestions?

**Barebones Test**

I installed CF 10 Developer Edition and enabled J2EE Session Variables

Created an Application.cfm with

```
<cfapplication name="test" sessionmanagement="Yes" setclientcookies="false">
```

and an index.cfm with

```
<h1>Cookie</h1>
<cfdump var="#cookie#">
<h1>Session</h1>
<cfdump var="#session#">
```

The `Session.URLToken` changes with every refresh

> CFID=2212&CFTOKEN=41db974c3d2eb4b6-640C21AE-FD53-499C-71FBEBA35D6B09E8&jsessionid=E28AA17629928FB6F9E17674AC85C7AA.cfusion
>
> CFID=2213&CFTOKEN=bb791a304929d0f5-6425021B-A31B-B9C8-3628AE391B0F48FF&jsessionid=E28AA17629928FB6F9E17674AC85C7AA.cfusion

**Further Thoughts**

The `CFID`and `CFTOKEN` are used in our login system to verify the user session matches, maybe I should change it to store and verify against the `JESSIONID`. Maybe it doesn't matter that the `CFID`and `CFTOKEN` change. The session scope is actually maintained, so this could be a completely non-issue.

```
<cfparam name="session.timestamp" default="#now()#">
```

Comment: Do you have any code to go along with this question?

Comment: Are you dealing with a single ColdFusion server or multiple load balanced servers? Did you clear (delete) the cookies after making the change?

Comment: @JamesAMohler - I'm just doing a dump of the scopes, to see that the CFID is fixed with cookie use and changes with J2EE session

Comment: @Miguel-F Single CF Server ColdFusion 10 Enterprise

Comment: Have you tried different browser? Do they all behave the same way?

Comment: @Miguel-F yes Chrome, IE and Firefox behave the same way, I'm currently installing CF 10 dev edition locally to test a barebone setup.

Comment: @Miguel-F Having conducted a barebones setup test, and used my brain some more - I believe perhaps our admin login's reliance on the CFID and CFTOKEN not changing, is our problem not ColdFusion. So perhaps we just need to use JSESSIONID instead.

Comment: _I believe perhaps our admin login's reliance on the CFID and CFTOKEN not changing, is our problem not ColdFusion_ Yep that could be the problem. There is no need for your code to use any of the session identifiers. Let the ColdFusion (JEE) server handle the session management for you. That's what it is designed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setClientCookies="false" means that coldfusion server will not create cookies for the current session. CFID and CFToken will still exist and will be non-persistent.
Check in your example that jsessionid value is same in both cases and that is what you should use instead of CFID & CFToken only if need be.
And you are correct, your session state is maintained as you have enabled J2EE session variables.

Comment: Yes this is the conclusion I have come to, was waiting for any final inputs before marking an answer - your summary will do fine :) thanks - The Jessionid persists pages to page.